# How to get bootstrap buttons to show active state?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a problem with a set of radio buttons.

```html
<div class="btn-group control-buttons" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
    <button type="button" class="btn">One</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn">Two</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn">Three</button>
</div>
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/dhbenson/LM9uW/

When the buttons are clicked, they don't ever stay depressed (i.e. none ever appear to be "active").

Does anyone know why not? What else do I need to do to make these buttons work properly?

*EDIT*

Ah, I see. I forgot to include the bootstrap js code.

This fiddle works: http://jsfiddle.net/dhbenson/qNeSS/

Comment: did u include all bootstrap related js and css...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the bootstrap javascript for that functionality.

Add this to your HTML head:

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This did nothing for me. Still no active state.

Comment: Looks like the resource isn't available there anymore, it redirects to getboostrap.com which details how to get it: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download

Comment: I have the right bootstrap.min.js. It still does nothing. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/uCbnr/

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```html
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox">
    <button type="button" class="btn">Left</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn">Middle</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn">Right</button>
</div>
```

and add one file i.e. `bootstrap-button.js`