# On/Off: switch button bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, uiswitch

**Here is my code-**

```
<div id="normal-toggle-button" class="toggle-button" style="width: 100px; height: 25px;">
            <div style="left: 0px; width: 150px;"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked"><span class="labelLeft" style="width: 50px; height: 25px; line-height: 25px;">ON</span><label for="" style="width: 50px; height: 25px;"></label><span class="labelRight" style="width: 50px; height: 25px; line-height: 25px;">OFF </span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Script-**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#normal-toggle-button').toggleButtons();
    });
```

I want a basic button given on this page- [Switch buttons](http://www.larentis.eu/bootstrap_toggle_buttons/)

I am doing all right. But something i still missed.

Check in here-
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stackmanoz/WvRZw/)

Comment: you need to style it of course!

Comment: I think this post will be helpful

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177159/jquery-toggle-checkboxes-on-off

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The simplest use of bootstrapSwitch

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WvRZw/474/)

```
<link href="bootstrap-switch.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap-switch.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox">
<script>
  $('input:checkbox').bootstrapSwitch();
</script>
```

Comment: It appears this no longer works.  Maybe with the latest version of bootstrap it broke?

Comment: @WingLeong I want to save the state of the button till it is not changed manually. Is it possible?

Comment: @user983983, use localStorage in javascript- http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Answer (score -1):

### class matters

You had the class as "toggle-button" still, change it to "switch"

Here is your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WvRZw/10/

```
 <div id="normal-toggle-button" class="toggle-button"....
```

change to

```
  <div id="normal-toggle-button" class="switch" ....
```

### css/javascript includes

You need to include the bootstrap javascript and css as well (see the resources section)
(also regarding including javascript and css: [How to get bootstrap buttons to show active state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14016530/how-to-get-bootstrap-buttons-to-show-active-state/14016644#14016644))

Comment: Ok, everything in your code was about "toggle-button".  Also needed the base bootstrap js/css.